# How do I glob and repeat command line argument with option repeated?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, glob

I want to run a command line program for multiple inputs like this

```
image_convert -I ./a.png -I ./b.png ...
```

The `-I` is mandatory before each file. Can I somehow do this for all png files in the directory using bash shell glob syntax, e.g., something like this

```
image_convert -I ./*.png
```

(this doesn't work)

Answer (score 2):

You could combine `printf` with `xargs`:

```sh
printf -- '-I\0%s\0' *.png | xargs -0 image_convert
```

Answer (score 1):

`image_convert -I ./*.png` would expand to something like: `image_convert -I ./a.png ./b.png`.

You can use a loop and an array instead:

```
args=()
for arg in ./*.png
do
  [ -f "$arg" ] || continue
  args+=("-I" "$arg")
done
image_convert "${args[@]}"
```

If you want to deal with a POSIX shell, then you can utilize the array `$@`:

```
set -- # empty $@
for arg in ./*.png
do
  [ -f "$arg" ] || continue
  set -- "$@" -I "$arg" # Re-set $@ with '-I "$arg"' added for each iteration
done
image_convert "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `xargs` from command line:

```
ls -1 ./*.png | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 image_convert -I
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `find` command.

```sh
find . -type f -iname '*.png' -exec image_convert -I '{}' \+
```